# What tool will help me track sentences and paragraphs in resumes and cover letters so I can use this database to tailor new ones?

Tags: tools, resume, cover-letter

I'm tailoring my resume over and over to highlight my experiences that best fit the needs of employers as described in their job listings. Not to overstate the obvious, but I do this by choosing bullet point items (sentence length) from various previous versions of my resume, developing new items as appropriate and tweaking the word choices and order to give the resume a "voice" that fits the advertised culture and the industry.

A cover letter is supposed to be written for each employer and tell them a story about why I'm a good fit for their opening. A cover letter should not simply restate information from my resume in paragraph form. Again, I create new cover letters based on paragraph chunks of previous ones.

What can I use as a database to manage the sentences and paragraphs from all previous resumes and cover letters, that will allow me to select the ones that I've already used and compile it into a new, tailored resume or cover letter, and provide me with material to develop new bullet points and paragraphs, without having to open all of my previous versions and start copying-and-pasting?

Comment: A spreadsheet program plus mail merge should get you started.

Comment: I do a similar thing as @Lauren Ipsum -- I have a spreadsheet with some of the most used phrases.  Most often, like you,  I start with my closest-matching cover letter, highlight what needs to change, add words in red to indicate points of what I want to communicate, and edit from there.
It may be useful to check out college career-help department's pages: they often have a list of useful resume verbs -- they may also have similar tools.  Otherwise, TWINE, the "choose your own adventure" writing web-app may be a good place to store and mix data?

Comment: Thank you both for the suggestions.

Comment: @April - I tried downloading TWINE, but couldn't really see an easy way to adapt this. Looks interesting though for when I have a bit more creative freedom time!

Comment: @LaurenIpsum - I opened Word to try your mail merge idea, but it seemed a bit too hacky to adapt to my needs. i do like the metaphor though: a wizard-like tool that goes through the sections of the resume and allows me to check off everything that I want included in the complete, exported document.

Comment: I think TWINE doesn't really do what I hope -- but ideally it could be a choose your own adventure -- paste in the job listing, check off your skills, find a supply of sentences/phrases you or others have used to express competence!

Comment: Hi and welcome. I wanted to ask, what is your coding proficiency? I think this could be automated in a programmatic fashion, but that would probably belong to another SE.

Comment: For a low-tech solution, you might try creating a master resume that contains absolutely everything and when it comes time to submit your job application, simply make a copy and delete the parts that don't pertain to that job. If you write new content, simply add it to the master.

Comment: Interesting approach @April - my problem is that job hunting is turning out to be a job in itself, and I was looking for something pretty close or easily adaptable to the job to be done... Thanks for the idea though!

Comment: @NofP I'm a django dabbler, dangerous enough to get a project like this started, but not enough to be sure that I could _quickly_ get it over the V1.0 finish line. You do raise a great point though: this may be more of a tech question than a writing question. Thanks for that thought!

Comment: I tried exactly that, @AdamJLimbert, and it looks like I might be going back to that if I can't find an easier way. Managing variations of sentences and versions was a hairball of a process, but it looks like your suggestion is the best I'll be able to do for now. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks Secespitus for putting a bounty on this question.  Lots of decent answers but they're all in the comments.  @April and others, write these up as answers!

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use an Excel workbook; the individual spreadsheets hold certain thematically divided elements like opening sentences, skills, personal qualities, relevant experience, etc... Within those spreadsheets there are further divisions based on the type of job I'm applying for, so a block of skill-sentences for desk jobs, a block for workshop positions etc... Creating a given resume or cover letter is then a fairly simple matter of looking at the job description and selecting the sentences to copy and paste into a Word document, or similar, that has the set elements of name, address, signature etc... and editing a little to get the "fit" smoothed out. I then save the finished work as a PDF if I'm using it online or just print it out for a hard copy.